# Creating multiple checkboxes with *ngFor

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngfor

I am trying to rewrite part of code written in Angular 5 which used three hard coded check boxes so they become dynamically created based on number of objects I get from back end.

In template there was:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Options 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="option1" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="context.option1"
               (change)="context.option1 = !context.option1"/>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Options 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="option2" [value]="false" [checked]="context.option2"
               (change)="context.option2 = !context.option2"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Options 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option3" name="option3" [value]="false" [checked]="context.option3"
               (change)="context.option3 = !context.option3"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

and in model (snippet):

```
export class SomeClass {
    public company: string;
    ...
    public option3: boolean = false;
    public option2: boolean = false;
    public option1: boolean = false;
    ...

    constructor(company: string) {
        this.company = company;
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I rewrote it like this:
Template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let option of this.context.someClassWithBean.someBean; let i = index">
        <label class="control-label">Options {{i}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option{{i}}" name="option{{i}}" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="context.options[i]"
               (change)="context.options[i] = !context.options[i]"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in model (snippet):

```
export class SomeClass {
    public company: string;
    ...
    public options: boolean [];
    ...

    constructor(company: string) {
        this.company = company;
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course I have problem. Code doesn't output index for Option (Option 0, Option 1...) and if I remove [i] from `(change)="context.options[i] = !context.options[i]` then it writes Option 1 etc., but I doubt that it work as now there is no index for array. On top of that I have

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

in both cases. And I am not sure if this is right way to do it at all.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of reference, here is what was solution:
In model, I had to initialize array:

```
public options: boolean[] = [];
```

and then in component I had to add:

```
if (this.context.options.length === 0) {
    this.context.someClassWithBean.someBean.forEach(() => {
        this.context.options.push(false);
    });
}
```